# Can I shut off the refrigerent line on my AC unit

Tags: hvac

I have a multi-split unit with valves according to the picture. One of the indoor units is not working properly and I would like to shut off the gas going to it. Can I just remove the caps (circled in red)  and use a hex key?

[image]

Comment: When I look at other multi-split units, there are always two connections for each unit, so it does not make sense that those valves are to add additional lines.

Comment: That's what _other_ units may do, but what do the instructions for _your_ unit say to do?

Answer (score 3):

On all of the multi-zone mini splits I have interacted with, you can cap off and disconnect an unused unit. The decommissioning procedure is located in the service manual. Typically it involves putting the zone to be removed in emergency mode. Then you shut off the liquid line until the suction line reaches vacuum, at which point you shut off the suction line off as well. Finally you disconnect the wiring to the indoor unit that you just removed. If you're not comfortable with reading the service manual and following these steps, or you don't have an HVAC manifold set so that you can monitor the pump down, you should hire an HVAC professional. This is a routine task and should cost just the service minimum to have done.

If you just shut those valves while leaving the wiring in place and the gas in the unit, you will likely have problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes one should expect to find a valve under those caps. As you indicated, it'll be operated with a hex key (almost certainly metric-sized).

I'm not sufficiently familiar with multi-zone systems to be confident as to whether it'll operate properly with the second zone closed off at the valve. It seems like a reasonable expectation, though.